# iPhone UILocalNotification values

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am creating several UILocalNotifications with different repeatIntervals.

All repeat intervals are assigned using a NSCalendarUnit, like

```
myNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
```

I am debugging. When I print the NSArray containing the notifications using

```
NSArray*  oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
NSLog(@"alarms = %@", oldNotifications);
```

I see the notification printed as this:

> **"{fire date = 2011-09-19
>   06:26:00 +0000, time zone = Europe/Lisbon (WEST) offset 3600
>   (Daylight), repeat interval = 512, next fire date = 2011-09-19
>   06:26:00 +0000}"**

Notice that the repeat interval is a number, in this example 512, but it can be 256, 0, whatever.

Where do I find the equivalence of these numbers withe the NSCalendarUnit? I need to know what they are, so I can debug. "Jump to definition" on Xcode does not shows the numbers.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh! I realized I could simple print the values like this:

```
NSLog(@"NSEraCalendarUnit = %d", NSEraCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSYearCalendarUnit = %d", NSYearCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSMonthCalendarUnit = %d", NSMonthCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSDayCalendarUnit = %d", NSDayCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSHourCalendarUnit = %d", NSHourCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSMinuteCalendarUnit = %d", NSMinuteCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSSecondCalendarUnit = %d", NSSecondCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSWeekCalendarUnit = %d", NSWeekCalendarUnit);
NSLog(@"NSWeekdayCalendarUnit = %d", NSWeekdayCalendarUnit);
```

... etc

to know the equivalence in integers.

Comment: ...or look at the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFCalendarRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001434-CH1g-C007681).

Comment: the references do not gives the integer values.

Comment: An excerpt from the reference: `kCFCalendarUnitWeekday = (1 << 9)`

Comment: this is klingon to me. If you can tell me how this can be translated in an integer, I appreciate.

Comment: `<<` is the left shift operator. It takes the binary representation of a value, and moves all the bits n places to the left, back-filling with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

```
if we use NSWeekCalendarUnit then we get this.
fire date = 2011-09-17 09:05:00 +0000, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 256, next fire date = 2011-09-17 09:05:00 +0000

if we use NSWeekdayCalendarUnit then we get this.

fire date = 2011-09-17 09:05:00 +0000, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = 512, next fire date = 2011-09-17 09:05:00 +0000

these are pre defind interval by ios we cant change it.
```